debian based docker build image not finding apt while building from CI/CD alpine based dind image
So I've been building my image for a while now locally with out any problem:
FROM python:3.12-slim
RUN apt update
{...}

Now I wanted to automate the deployment of this image so I setup my gitlab-ci.yml to the following:
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

before_script:
  - apk add bash ncurses docker-compose
  - apk add --no-cache openssh-client bash
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY

{...}

build-controller-image:
  tags:
    - linux_docker_privileged
  stage: build
  script:
    - version=$(bash ./scripts/script_get_version.sh "processing" "docker_versions.txt")
    - docker build -t processing:$version --platform linux/arm64 processing
  when: manual

{...}


The job starts and pulls the python image but fail on :
[ 2/19] RUN apt update
0.440 exec /bin/sh: no such file or directory
ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt update]: exit code: 1

the python image is debian based so it should have no problem doing the apt update. is there something I'm not correctly doing with dind?
I tried pulling the image with the same hash locally to see if I could reproduce the problem from my ci/cd with out any luck. everything still builds locally

Do other commands work? How is qemu installed on the CI server? Does the build work for the build server's platform? What is the digest of the pulled base image on the build server? The full output of the build and a [mcve] may help.

it was a problem related to the system architecture vs container architecture. using buildx allowed me to build the image regardless of the machine used. see: https://docs.docker.com/build/architecture/ for more details
